# Display all post image gallery using the shortcode [gallery]

Tags: wordpress, preg-match, gallery, image-gallery, shortcode

I want to display the images from the post gallery with the "gallery". Like that :`<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?>`

After some search, I learned that we needed to use a "preg_match" function to get the ids of the images gallery. Something like that :

```
$post_content = $post->post_content;
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
```

But I don't know how to use it ... I'm a newbie and it's quite difficult for me to use that.
Should I put this code in my functions file ? If yes how can I do that please ?

The aim it's to put a final code like that : `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gallery ids="$array_id"]' ); ?>`

Thank you and sorry for my english !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, so I share this with you. Maybe someone will be interested by that.

I modified the following code :

```
$post_content = $post->post_content;
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
```

Into :

```
<?php
global $post;

    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
    $images_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
echo do_shortcode('[gallery type="slideshow" ids="'. implode(',', array_slice($images_id, 0, 3)).' ,"]');
?>
```

And I inserted this in my custom `format-gallery.php` and it works so fine. Notice that I have limited automatically the number of ids returned with an `array_slice()`.

I hope that will help someone.